# Query item in Xpath

Tags: content-search, sitecore-query

i have 2 sites, A and B in Sitecore. Some items in site A are linked to items in site B. I need a query to list all items in site A that are linked to any items in site B.

I can't touch in code. Any solution to query in sitecore query notation or xpath?

Comment: How the items are linked? Is it via fields like droplink, multilist?

Comment: The item have link field,it linked some where in site B.

Comment: Sitecore Powershell might help you..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because abandoned by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since Sitecore 7, there has been an admin tool called LINQ ScratchPad.

This could allow you to find the items.

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/sitecore-7-linqscratchpad